# How can I check for which platform a library is build

Tags: c, linux

I am cross compiling for an RX platform under linux, but how can I check if the library is built for the right platform?

Does anyone knows what the command is under linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output is in ELF format (which you can determine by typing `file <filename>`) than you can use the `readelf` and/or `objdump` commands to inspect it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `file` see [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) to get meta information for a file. E.g. the architecture that it is compiled for.